# How do I implement no-refresh submit via a link rather than a button?

Tags: jquery, ajax, submit

I have a series of links:

```
<a href="#">insert into database1</a>
<a href="#">insert into database2</a>
<a href="#">insert into database3</a>
```

I want to be able to click the link, then the link will be an action to insert things to the desired database (the link acts like a button).

Comment: Are you using a library like jQuery or are you writing straight JavaScript?

Comment: at the end of your jQuery function write `return false;`. your page will not refresh by this.

Comment: the problem I am having is trying to set it up so I can grab the correct link, then implement logic to do the inserting without refresh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like the following:

```
$('a').click(function() {

var link = $(this);

$.ajax({
  url: link.attr('href'),
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: "json",
  error: function(req, resulttype, exc)
  {
    console.log('Something went wrong with the request');
  },
  success: function(data)
  {
    if (data.result == 'success') {
      console.log('Data added to database');
    } else {
      console.log('Couldnt add to database');
    }
  }
});

   return false;
});
```

You can change the parameters where needed.

And the backend side would like something like (PHP example).

```
// do database stuff

print(json_encode(array('result'=>'success')));
```